# Populating listbox vb6 with recordset

Tags: vb6

I have a recordset populated from a stored procedure

```
    Set PesquisaTabela = cmd.Execute
    If Not PesquisaTabela.EOF Then
      txtUS.Text = PesquisaTabela.Fields(0)
    end if
```

How can I use this recordset to populate an fplist / listbox in VB6  ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a recordset with several rows, you will need to loop through the rows to populate the listbox. And instead of a textbox, you ill need to use a Listbox I guess.

One way of doing it is as follows;

```
Dim iIndex as integer
If Not Recordset Is Nothing Then

  For iIndex = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1

    ListBox.Add(Recordset.Fields(iIndex).Column) 

  Next iIndex

End if
```

you can also use the While loop on the recordset

```
 If Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Recordset.MoveFirst
       While Not Recordset.EOF
         ...

         Recordset.MoveNext
       Wend
 End if
```

Comment: In the first example, the counter will only count the number of **columns** in the output, not the number of rows.  As such, this will not really be suitable for populating the listbox.  The While loop from the second example would work in this instance in place of the For loop.  I also had problems with the second example, with the RecordCount being set to -1 - this was because it was never populated where my recordset was of the Forward Only type, which does not support it.